# Extracting the Company property from a Word document using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel 2010 and VBA to reorganize some Word documents on my C:\ drive and I want to pull the "Company" property of each document into a sheet containing a list of documents.  The full file path of each document appears in row A (like so: "C:\folder\subfolder\file.doc"),and I would like to populate the corresponding "Company"  property in row F.

I'm trying to write a macro for a custom Excel function DocCompany that will use a text string containing a local filepath to return the "Company" property of the document that the filepath identifies.
I've had better luck with the Last Modified and File Size properties, as both have dedicated VBA functions (FILEDATETIME and FILELEN, respectively).  In each case, all I had to do was write a macro for a custom Excel function that returns the result of the VBA function for a file path string located in the sheet.

*Given the following function,* =GetFileDateTime(A1) *will return the last save date for the document identified by the filepath string contained in A1.*

```
Function GetFileDateTime(FileName As String) As Date
    GetFileDateTime = FileDateTime(FileName)
End Function
```

*Given the following function,* =FileSize(A1) *will return the file size in bytes of the document identified by the filepath string contained in A1.*

```
Function FileSize(FileName As String)
    FileSize = FileLen(FileName)
End Function
```

However, the Company property has no corresponding VBA function, so (as I said above), I want to write a macro defining a custom Excel function DocCompany that will accept a local filepath string as input and use it to output the Company property of the document.

This is what my macro looks like right now:

```
Function CompanyID(FileName As String) As String
    CompanyID = Documents(FileName).Open
    Documents(FileName).BuiltinDocumentProperties (wdPropertyCompany)
End Function
```

When I try to save it, Excel returns the error message "Compile error: Sub or Function not defined". Then it selects the reference to the "Documents" collection in the second row.

Why does Excel insist that I define "Documents" as a variable when every reference I can find confirms that it IS in fact an object or collection?  What can I do to make this code work?  Do I need to take a different approach?

Comment: You can get this to work as a UDF as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28685057/2127508) but, if you have to create a Word application object every time, then the UDF will be painfully slow to run. You would also need to ensure that you are meticulous in disposing of every Word application object that gets created

Answer (score 1):

> Why does Excel insist that I define "Documents" as a variable when every reference I can find confirms that it IS in fact an object or collection?

Since `Documents` is not part of the Excel object model, it is being interpreted as a variable. You need to bind Word to the Excel instance, and reference that instance of the Word Application class.

```
Function CompanyID(FileName As String) As String
    Dim wdApp as Object 'WOrd.Application
    Dim doc as Object 'Word.Document
    Const wdPropertyCompany as Long = 21 'Explicit reference for late-bound Word Application

    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set doc = wdApp.Documents.Open(FileName)
    CompanyID = doc.BuiltinDocumentProperties (wdPropertyCompany)
    doc.Close False

End Function
```

Comment: Should be `Set doc = wdApp.Documents.Open(FileName)`, otherwise a "Bad filename" error will occur

Comment: Thanks!  It makes sense that Excel would have you somehow indicate that you intend to access the Word object model.

However, when I execute your macro, I get a '#NAME' error.  When I choose _Show Calculation Steps..._, it displays a _Save As_ window with the name of the document referenced by the function instance in the _Save As_ field.

I should've told you the documents in the list aren't open(?)  The Documents object seems to be defined as open documents--does this macro need an "open document" task, or can you access closed document properties?

(It seems like you should be able to.)

Comment: Try `doc.Close False` to prevent the `SaveAs` dialog (and this should prevent the error).

Answer (score 0):

```
Function F_snb(c00)
  With GetObject(c00)
    F_snb = .BuiltinDocumentProperties(21)
    .Close 0
  End With
End Function
```

in A2: G:\OF\example.docx

in D2: =F_snb(A2)

Comment: Thank you, @snb!

Replaced M_snb with my Function name and tried to implement in my sheet by referencing the filepath as a string in another cell '=CompanyID(A1)'.  I get a '#NAME?' error.  When I Show Calculation Steps, a message box with the company property appears.

How do I forego the message box and display the company property as the formula result?