# Extracting the Content Control property from a Word document using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

My question is somewhat similar to this post [Extracting the Company property from a Word document using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684664/extracting-the-company-property-from-a-word-document-using-excel-vba)

I am looking to extract the **Content Control Properties** instead of BuiltinDocumentProperties of MSWord.

I'm novice in VBA, any code snippet that can extract the Content Control Property from MS Word Document, will be of great help to me.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Stackoverflow does not write code for you. Show an attempt to solve the problem first.

Comment: Or, at the very least, give examples of what properties you want to access for what kinds of content controls...

Answer (score 1):

As a starter: Consider that there are a large number of `ContentControl Properties` (Word) so being more specific in your question would help and definitely showing an attempt to code it.

The list given here [ContentControl Properties (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn320579.aspx) outlines the different properties and gives an indication of the read write status.  I am not going to post a summary of the link, but will point out, it details what you can see in the object browser in a more legible fashion.

This [article](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_controls.html) gives general descriptions and limitations for each of the types. It is more descriptive of the actual usage of the controls and might aid you in refining your code.

[image: Top rows of document]

You can loop over controls as a collection. I have written this for implementation within Word; the link you gave shows you how to implement this in Excel referencing Word.

```
Public Sub test()

Dim ContentControl As ContentControl

For Each ContentControl In ThisDocument.ContentControls

   Debug.Print ContentControl.Type

Next ContentControl

End Sub
```

You could write some code that after you have checked the types present (as above) then writes out the properties (where applicable) to a text file or a worksheet.

Probably the best way to go about exploring this would be to open the object browser and read the associated information against each member of the class and write your code in the context of that.

[image: Object browser]

If you want to access the controls in the same way as the link you provided, have a look at the available [WdContentControlType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/wdcontentcontroltype-enumeration-word)

[image: Enumerations]

Here is a simple example of retrieving an item (adapting code by @DavidZemens from your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684664/extracting-the-company-property-from-a-word-document-using-excel-vba) and from [Astrid](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/MixedDocProps.htm). Gives you a starter for 10 on how to access from Excel. Note this is tailored to a particular enumeration (`8` for `wdContentControlCheckBox`), which returns a boolean; this is why understanding better your objectives and seeing your attempt would help.

```
Option Explicit

Public cc As Object

Public Sub Testing()

  Dim PropVal As Boolean
  Const wdContentControlCheckBox As Long = 8

  PropVal = ReadProp(wdContentControlCheckBox, "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test.docm")

  MsgBox PropVal

End Sub

Function ReadProp(ByVal sPropName As Long, ByVal FileName As String) As Boolean

    Dim wdApp As Object 'Word.Application
    Dim doc As Object 'Word.Document

    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set doc = wdApp.Documents.Open(FileName, ReadOnly:=True)

    Dim bCustom As Boolean
    Dim sValue As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandlerReadProp
  'Try the built-in properties first
  'An error will occur if the property doesn't exist
    sValue = doc.BuiltinDocumentProperties(sPropName).Value
    ReadProp = CBool(sValue)

Exit Function

ContinueCustom:
  bCustom = True

Custom:
  sValue = doc.CustomDocumentProperties(sPropName).Value
  ReadProp = CBool(sValue)
  Exit Function

ErrHandlerReadProp:
  Err.Clear
  'The boolean bCustom has the value False, if this is the first
  'time that the errorhandler is runned
  If Not bCustom Then
    'Continue to see if the property is a custom documentproperty
    Resume ContinueCustom
  Else
    'The property wasn't found, return an empty string
   ' ReadProp = "" ''Commented out by QHarr
    Msgbox "Property not found"
    Exit Function
  End If

End Function
```